# Debugging wine on OS X?

Tags: macos, homebrew, wine

I installed wine using homebrew, and now I've been working on getting SolidWorks to run on OS X through wine, fixing the errors one by one.

Here's the error I'm currently stuck on:

```
err:winediag:ODBC_LoadDriverManager failed to open library "libodbc.dylib": dlopen(libodbc.dylib, 265): no suitable image found.
```

I've tried installing unixodbc with homebrew, but then it gives this error instead:

```
err:winediag:ODBC_LoadDriverManager failed to open library "libodbc.dylib": dlopen(libodbc.dylib, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 libodbc.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
 /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I checked, and I have the 64 bit version of libODBC.

```
$ file /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Is there a way to install ODBC in 32 bit mode or compile it from source? Thanks!

PS. I've also tried installing unixobdc through mac ports, but wine doesn't find it at all then.

Update:
I downloaded the source from www.unixodbc.org and compiled it in 32bit mode. I also moved the libodbc.dylib to /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib. I've also verified that it is 32 bit.

```
file /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

The issue is now wine doesn't detect it.

```
err:winediag:SQLDrivers No ODBC drivers could be found. Check the settings for your libodbc provider.
```

Any advice?

Comment: You will need to compile the 32 bit version IF homebrew lacks a formulae for it.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 I didn't fine a homebrew formula, so I did compile it. I updated the question to reflect this. The issue is now it doesn't detect the 32bit library.

Comment: Install the driver as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

May be You can compile UnixODBC x32 from source http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/UnixODBC_(FireDAC)

```
export CFLAGS=-m32
wget ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/unixODBC-2.3.4.tar.gz
tar -zxvf unixODBC-2.3.4.tar.gz
cd unixODBC-2.3.4
./configure --enable-gui=no --enable-drivers=no --enable-stats=no --enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```